# subtour elimination constraints in VRP exact mathematical formulation

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, vehicle-routing, mathematical-expressions, operations-research

I'm formulating a variant of VRP where all `k` vehicles have unique start locations while all of them end at a common depot which is different from all these `k` start locations.

While writing exact mathematical formulation for this problem, do we still need to write subtour elimination constraints ?